# Use SQL database in my flash game

Tags: php, sql, flash

I am working on a blackjack game, and I need to change the point value to the point value in my SQL database of my user.

I already have the script in PHP for catching the point of the current connected user on my website, but need to use this value in my flash game.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require('../../../php/config.php');
    if (empty($_SESSION['pseudo'])) {
        $point = 0;
    }
    else {
        $req = $db->query("SELECT points FROM membres WHERE id = \"" . $_SESSION['id'] . "\"");
        $res = $req->fetch();
        $point = $res['points'];
    }
    echo $point;
?>
```

And I don't know how to connect this to my flash game for using the point variable.

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection and quoting headaches. To prevent that, use prepared statements and parameter binding. Here are the links for more information for [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)
 and [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score -1):

You would do an update query

```
$req = $db->query("UPDATE membres WHERE id = x ....
```

you can learn more about querys here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp .

Also are you sure you need to use sql in your flash game? Why not just use a double array?